# How to warp an image using a mesh in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, transformation

I want to warp an image using a mesh, the mesh is an array of shape WxHx2. I have two channels: one for x and the other for y, they tell us how much distortion in that zone we will have.

If I create a grid with that distortion it is something like this:
[image]

Now I want to interpolate an image using this grid. If the distortion is beyond the image size it will be cut.

I have tried with `ImageOps.deform` and `Image.Image.transform` but I can't get it to work.

With `ImageOps` we need to create a deformer object like:

```py
class SingleDeformer:
  def getmesh(self, img):
    #Map a target rectangle onto a source quad
     return [(
            # target rectangle
            (20, 10, 30, 20),
            # corresponding source quadrilateral
            (0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 20, 10, 0)
            )]
```

The target needs two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and in this case I would need the target to be four points (x,y) as the source quadrilateral which requires to be:

1. Top left
2. Bottom left
3. Bottom right
4. Top right

I can have the four source as quadrilateral but the target is not a a square, maybe I'm missing something, any help is appreciated.

Comment: don't use opencv. it's not for drawing. use opengl or something. it's made for drawing. -- the "warpAffine" code that people keep copying is *a horrible hack*, very bad code, could be improved a lot. do not use it.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform

Comment: I wonder why `ImageOps.deform` is not working for you. Can you please add your current code to the question and describe where you got stuck? As a new contributor you may also find it useful to read [ask].

Comment: ```ImageOps.deform``` uses only two points for the target, while it takes four for the source. My target is not exactly a perfect square/rectangle.